# How to properly store and give away images with different sizes

Tags: nginx

For my web application I need different sizes of the same image on different elements of different pages, how should I do it?

Store different sizes or for certain url's generate images with appropriate sizes (For example: media/images/x/x/image/400x400)? If the latter, how can I implement this generation of different sizes in nginx?

Comment: Nginx won't be able to resize a image for you. have a look to 'imagemagic'